# angular injecting resolve into controller logging undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

I have the following resolve:

```
.state('posts', {
      url: '/posts/{id}',
      templateUrl: 'posts.html',
      controller: 'postsController as postsCtrl',
      resolve: {
        post: getSinglePostWrapper
      }
    })
```

and helper function

```
getSinglePostWrapper.$inject = ['postsService', '$stateParams'];
function getSinglePostWrapper(postsService, $stateParams) {
    return postsService.getSinglePost($stateParams.id);
}
```

and my controller looks like this:

```
angular.module('flapperNews')
.controller('postsController', postsController);

postsController.$inject = ['postsService', 'post'];

function postsController(postsService, post) { 
   var vm = this;
   vm.post = post;
   console.log(post); //undefined here
}
```

I'm getting an undefined "post" when I try to inject the post from the resolve. I tried logging the post in the `getSinglePostWrapper` function, and it logs the correct object. I seem to be losing some binding or something from the resolve to the controller.

posts service

```
angular.module('flapperNews')
.factory('postsService', postsService);

postsService.$inject = ['httpService'];

function postsService(httpService) {
  return {
        getSinglePost: getSinglePost
  }
  function getSinglePost(postId) {
        httpService.baseGet('/posts/' + postId)
        .then(function(data) {
            return data;
        }, function(data) {});
  }
}
```

httpservice

```
angular.module('httpService', [])
.factory('httpService', httpService);

httpService.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];

function httpService($http, $q) {
  return {
        baseGet: baseGet
  }
  function baseGet(url) {
        return $http.get(url).then(
                function (result) {
                    return result.data;
                },
                function (result) {
                    return $q.reject(result);
                }
        );
    }

}
```

and I've injected httpservice into the first place I declare the flapperNews module.

FYI- everything is working. Other http requests are fine. This one is fine too. It just doesn't inject the post into the controller.

Comment: I don't see why this wouldn't work. Can you post your service code?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another resolve or dependency named `post`?

Comment: yep, that's my only resolve on that controller. and the only dependency named post

Comment: You must some kind of error somewhere else. [Here's a similar plunker that does work.](http://plnkr.co/edit/GtVRh1TVwCM0ajmGiV3d?p=preview)

Comment: must be, leave that plunkr up there so I can study it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promise chain breaks here.

```
  function getSinglePost(postId) {
        httpService.baseGet('/posts/' + postId)
        .then(function(data) {
            return data;
        }, function(data) {});
  }
```

You don't return the promise, hence `post` will be resolved to `undefined` before `httpService.baseGet` request has been finished.

Comment: Wow, very nice catch! Your second point is incorrect though. ui-router handles 'unwrapping' the promise.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.state('posts', {
      url: '/posts/{id}',
      templateUrl: 'posts.html',
      controller: 'postsController as postsCtrl',
      resolve: {
        post: function('postsService', '$stateParams') {
           return postsService.getSinglePost($stateParams.id);
      }
    })

angular.module('flapperNews')
.controller('postsController', function($scope, post){
    $scope.post = post;
   console.log($scope.post); //undefined here
});
```

Comment: well I need to inject the postsService and stateParams

Comment: I'm trying to avoid that syntax. I'd like to keep my functions more modular.

Comment: What are you trying to keep modular? This code is clean, lean and should work if your service is done correctly. This seems to be be the standard from what I have seen for ui-router / angular controller AND it has the added benefit of working.

Comment: There is no standard. But the closest thing we do have to one even advocates using named over anonymous functions.  https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y024

Comment: Sure, JP style has the potential in migrating the codebase to classes, but @Enkode has the point. I believe that JP had good intentions when popularizing his styleguide, but generally it is abused and the code is barely readable when compared to Angular native syntax.